# How to filter array of arrays of array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to filter an array of arrays of objects, but it does not work.

```
   constructNewGrid(filterText){
      if(searchText == ""){
        this.constructedGrid = this.fullGrid;
        return;
      }
      this.constructedGrid = [];
      this.constructedGrid = this.fullGrid.filter(array => array.filter(obj => {
        if(obj.name == filterText)
          return obj;
      }));
      console.log(this.constructedGrid);
   }
```

I want to return an array of arrays with the correct object if found one but when I console log it `constructedGrid`is the same array but why?
The code should go to the first array should look up whether there is an object with the name equals to the filter text it should return the array with the corrosponding object and then the next array should be checked and so on.

This, would be the format:

```
[ 
  [[{name: string}], empty, empty], // array of lenth 3 
  [empty, empty, [{name: string}], empty], // array of length 4 
   ... 
]
```

If one object is found it should push it in an array separately such that if two objects where found in the same array, it should put them both in separately push them in two separat arrays and those should be in one single array:
Result should be

```
[
 [[obj1]],
 [[obj2]],
 ...
]
```

It seems in possible for me. I got sometime an error that I am out of memory haha...

Comment: What should it do if the array is completely empty once all empty entries have been removed from it? E.g., it doesn't even have one object in it?

Comment: If that is the case, I would handle it myselfe in my HTML-fille with ngIf: But not only the empty entries should be removed, objects should be checked if the property name equals the filterText. There can be more than one objects in a single array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `map` in addition to `filter`, because `filter` just decides whether to keep what's there, it doesn't *change* what's there. `map` does. Something like this:

```
  this.constructedGrid = this.fullGrid
      // Map the inner array to one that only has matching entries
      .map(array => array.filter(obj => obj && obj.name === filterText))
      // Remove blank inner arrays from the overall array
      .filter(array => array.length);
```

Live Example:

```js
const fullGrid = [ 
  [[{name: "target"}], , ],
  [, null, [{name: "target"}], undefined],
];
const filterText = "target";

const constructedGrid = fullGrid
      // Map the inner array to one that only has matching entries
      .map(array => array.filter(obj => obj && obj[0] && obj[0].name === filterText))
      // Remove blank inner arrays from the overall array
      .filter(array => array.length);
console.log(constructedGrid);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Note that you only need that second `filter` if you want to remove arrays that are completely empty from the outer array. If you want to leave them, just remove that call. *Edit: From your reply to my question on the question, it sounds like you want to remove that second `.filter`.*

Note the guard in the first `filter`, the `obj && obj[0] &&` part. It's there because you said sometimes array entries are "empty." I don't know if you literally meant empty — a sparse array — or entries that are `undefined`. If you literally meant *empty* (a sparse array), you don't need the guard, but it's probably best to have it.

As of ES2020, you could use the optional chaining operator instead:

```
.filter(obj => obj?.[0]?.name === filterText)
```

`obj?.[0]?.name` evaluates to `undefined` if `obj` is `null` or `undefined`, or `obj[0]` is `null` or `undefined`; it evaluates to `obj[0].name` otherwise. Since `undefined === filterText` will be false, entries with a `null` or `undefined` `obj` will be left out. Again, though, new feature, you'll need to check support on your target browsers if you're not transpiling.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the concise answer! Somehow there is no found object even though the name is exactly the same. Do you know where the problem may is?

Comment: Can I console log my object in the map function somehow?

Comment: I am very sorry, the format was wrong. This would be the right: Array [Array(1), Array(1), empty × 3] as in the console but now I know that I have to use map! I try it myself!

Comment: @Logik Ah! So there's another layer of array in there... I'll update. Is the innermost array always just one long?

Comment: Exactly the whole format : ```[ 
  [[{name: string}], empty, empty], // array of lenth 3 
  [empty, empty, [{name: string}], empty], // array of length 4 
   ... 
]```